# How to split parts for column data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL, I have a table, in that table column have following data

```
/message/charge/392bd2c574-90e7-da9f70ed01b2/text
```

I executed my query

```
select message from emp_data;
```

output:

```
/message/charge/392bd2c574-90e7-da9f70ed01b2/text
```

but I want only

```
392bd2c574-90e7-da9f70ed01b2
```

value in output so how to split it through SQL query

Comment: Search for `substring`, depending on your data you may also need `patindex`

Comment: So you want the text between the two final `/`s?

Comment: @jarlh: yes but how to split it i have lot of data in my table but all the data same as **/message/charge/392bd2c574-90e7-da9f70ed01b2/text**, **/message/charge/** and **/text** is same only changing **392bd2c574-90e7-da9f70ed01b2** value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try substring_index function-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('/message/charge/392bd2c574-90e7-da9f70ed01b2/text','/',-2),'/',1);
```

You can use below query including your field and table-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`message`,'/',-2),'/',1) FROM emp_data;
```

Note: Further you can add other fields and where condition as per your requirement.

Comment: it is not working. My table name is emp_data and column name is message.so how to write query.

Comment: it shows **ORA-00904:"SUBSTRING_INDEX":invalid identifier**

Comment: @Sri... Judging from the error code, you are using `oracle`, not `mysql` as your question is tagged.

Comment: @Sri : each database language have its own functions...so it will work with mysql but not true for other like oracle or MSSQL.

Comment: This answer will only work in `mysql`. You should tag your question properly to get good answers. (@Zafar, sorry for hijacking your answer..)

Comment: @ Zafar Malik.. my problem is solved **select regexp_substr(message,'[^/]+',1,3) from emp_data;**

Comment: Great...enjoy...by the way which database you are using mssql/oracle or any other.

Comment: oracle 10g. Thanks for your help.